# Filtering a table containing Hex Data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filtering

I currently have a table (data) containing many different data types however, I am trying to access the rows containing a certain Hex value in a column. Below is everything I have tried so far:

```
data=

Entry No | Time        | Word
---------|-------------|-------
1        | 000:123:456 | 0123  
2        | 000:123:457 | A0A0
3        | 000:123:543 | F0F0
4        | 000:124:123 | FFA0
5        | 000:124:987 | 2A0F


Msg = find(strcmp('F0F0', data.Col));

Msg = find(ismember(data.Col,'F0F0')); 

Msg = strfind(data.Col, 'F0F0');

Msg = data(data{:, 20} == F0F0,:);
```

Due to the different datatypes in other columns I also cannot convert the table to an array.
If you have any suggestions on how I can do this, that would be great.

Comment: Try adding a [mcve]

Comment: edit your question to include a small example of what `data` looks like

Comment: Apologies, edited to include a sample table.

Comment: is data a matlab [table](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html)?

Comment: @Vahe It's read in from a csv file using readtable.